# clicking element in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i have two windows.

One parent and the second an iframe. When a link is clicked inside of the iframe, i am able to effect the element in the parent window, but only certain things.

I am able to add Class without any problems, but when i want to trigger a click then it won't work.

Here is the working code for adding class:

parent window:

```
<a href="#/June-2013" id="page1">Name1</a>
<a href="#/Cover" id="page2">Name2</a>
<a href="#/Editorial-Cover" id="page3">Name3</a>
<a href="#/Webcast" id="page4">Name4</a>
<a href="#/Intuit" id="page5">Name5</a>
```

Iframe:

```
<div class="page5">link</div>

<script>
  $('.page5').click(function(){
     parent.top.$('#page5').addClass('classadded');
  });
</script>
```

But when i try

```
<script>
  $('.page5').click(function(){
     parent.top.$('#page5').trigger('click');
  });
</script>
```

nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jan

PS: their both on the same domain

Comment: Have you tried `window.parent.top.$('#page5').trigger('click');`?

Comment: Are you sure you have a click handler (attached via jQuery) on #page5?

Comment: @Joe, tried, didn't work

Comment: @Stejsi - try Brett's answer and use `parent.top.$('#page5')[0].click();`.

Comment: @Joe, thanks a lot for your help. this approach - parent.top.$('#page5')[0].click(); worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a jQuery guy, but based on my testing at http://jsfiddle.net/kB3Jz/4/ , even when within the same frame, trigger is only working with jQuery-attached events, not the default click nor directly-DOM-attached events....

HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com" id="page5">Name5</a>
<div class="page5">link</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.page5').click(function(){
    $('#page5').trigger('click');
});
$('#page5')[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('hello'); // Won't be triggered
});

$('#page5').click(function () {
    alert('hello2'); // Will be triggered
});
```

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) do say:

> "For both plain objects and DOM objects other than window, if a
>   triggered event name matches the name of a property on the object,
>   jQuery will attempt to invoke the property as a method if no event
>   handler calls event.preventDefault()"

...so it would seem trigger should work (since clicking on the DOM object via `$('#page5')[0].click()` works), but for some reason, it doesn't--maybe it's simply that jQuery's expressed "attempt to invoke" has failed for some reason...

I'd therefore suggest changing `window.location` via a jQuery-added click handler on #page5

Comment: Are you sure you're not clicking the link? I'm testing in Firefox, u?

Comment: i am testing in both firefox and chrome

Comment: Brett, i can get the alert message (it's the same as with the addClass), but i need to trigger the click on the link in the parent window. Maybe a different approach would be to have a jquery that would trigger click within the parent window based on the class i am adding

Comment: thanks a lot, parent.top.$('#page5')[0].click(); this approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
parent.location = parent.top.$('#page5').attr('href');
```

or

```
parent.location = parent.$('#page5').attr('href');
```